# How to show all fields contains a text?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have SQL table and I want to display all rows that their `Name` column contains the user entered text. how to do so?

I am doing it with C# on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your attempts and explain where you are stuck. There are many ways to do this and we need to see how you have approached it, so we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table where Name is not null
select * from Table where Name is not null and Name<>''
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this query

```
sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand();
cmd="Select * from tablename where Name ='" + textboxid.text + "'";
```

Here,tablename is the name of the table u have created and textbox id is the id of the textbox in which u will enter name.

Comment: When building queries that use raw user input, you should always use parameters to ensure that your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) for how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tablename where DATALENGTH(Name) > 0
```

Try this query in your SQLCommand Object..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses query parameters:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
   string.Format("Select * from Table where Name = @NameInput"), SqlConnection);

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@NameInput";
param.Value = textbox.Text;
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
```